# Header of thesis with predefined template

Tags: header-footer

I am writing a thesis with predefined template. However, the headers  conflict with the requirement. Here are the defined code in the thesis.cls file for headers and footers.

```
\def\ps@thesis@headings{%
    \def\@oddhead{\vbox to\headheight{%
        \hb@xt@\textwidth{ \hfill\wuhao\song\leftmark\hfill}
        \vskip2pt\hbox{\vrule width\textwidth height0.4pt depth0pt}}}
    \def\@evenhead{\vbox to\headheight{%
        \hb@xt@\textwidth{\wuhao\song
        \hfill\leftmark\hfill }
        \vskip2pt\hbox{\vrule width\textwidth height0.4pt depth0pt}}}
    \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\wuhao\thepage\hfil}
    \let\@evenfoot=\@oddfoot}
```

The above code produce a single sided header while my university requires a double sided header. What can I do to force the cls to switch to the correct style?

Comment: You can probably use package `fancyhdr` to customize the headers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just a guess: Load the class with the `twoside` option, i.e., `\documentclass[... ,twoside,...]{yourthesisclass}`. The code above distinguishes between headers on odd and even pages, but maybe isn't activated. If this doesn't help, you have to provide the preamble of your document (`\documentclass` ... `\begin{document}`) as well as a link to the class file if it is not a standard class.

Comment: Moreover, you probably need something like `\pagestyle{thesis}` somewhere in the preamble.